# How to import the Navigation function in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I am following a tutorial on how to switch pages in flutter so I know that my code isn't necessarily wrong, however I keep getting an error with the way I am importing my classes. I have 2 pages and i'm not sure how to properly import them

The way the tutorial says to import it is: " import 'package:overflown/page2.dart'; "
but I get the error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:overflown/page2.dart'. When I try to do it this way.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In `package:overflown/page2.dart'`,

- `overflown` is the name of your project you find in the pubspec.yaml
- `page2.dart` is the path to the page named `page2.dart`.

have to modify the import path to that to your page path.

Example

You have a project with name `testproject` and a folder structure

- lib

  - main.dart
  - page1.dart

The import should be

```
'package:testproject/page1.dart'
```